# BoxShadow and BorderRadius do not appear in IE with Javascript and CSS?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sharepoint

I got into a trouble that in the SharePoint, the Box-shadow, Border-radius and the showToggle's div tag don't appear in IE, but it runs very well in FF and Chrome.

Please let me know what is going wrong here.

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/sndGB)**</kbd>

HTML

```
<table id="showRoom">
    <tr class="box_shadow">
        <td class="text_plant_address">
            <span class="text_plant">Plant 1</span>

            <!-- <br /> <span class="text_address">Street 2, Dong An Industrial Park</span> -->
        </td>
        <td class="toggle_des">
            <div class="news_column1"> 
                <a class="link_to_book" target="_blank" href="http://google.com">
                    <span class="circle_plant">P1</span>
                    <span class="imgswap">Showroom 1</span>
                    <div class="news_img">
                        <div class="description_room">
                            <p class="info_room">Book Now!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="_space"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css

```
#showRoom {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
    padding: 0;
}
.box_shadow {
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family:'Scada', sans-serif;
    display: block;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
    box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
}
.text_plant_address {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family:'Scada', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
._space {
    width: 20px;
}
.link_to_book {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.toggle_des a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.text_plant {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    font-family: ballpark_weiner, Arial;
    font-size: 22px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    height: 145px;
    width: auto;
}
.text_address {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Arial;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.news_column1 {
    background-color: #FF9393;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*background-color: #F67C78;*/
    /*background-color: #FFF;*/
    /*border-radius: 15px;*/
}
.news_column2 {
    background-color: #E39EE4;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*background-color: #FFF;*/
    /*border-radius: 15px;*/
}
.news_column3 {
    background-color: #48B1F3;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*background-color: #FFF;*/
    /*border-radius: 15px;*/
}
.news_column4 {
    background-color: #9ACF52;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*background-color: #FFF;*/
    /*border-radius: 15px;*/
}
.news_img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    font-family:'Times New Roman';
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.95;
    /*border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;*/
}
.description_room {
    width: 150px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.info_room {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #FFF;
    /* transform: rotate(-10deg); */
    /* -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg); /* IE 9 */
    /* -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}
.circle_plant {
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 65px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #111111;
    opacity: 0.3;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 42.5px 0 42.5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 32.5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 32.5px;
    border-radius: 32.5px;
}
.imgswap {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.5;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-family: Stark;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table tr .toggle_des").hover(function (e) {
        $(this).find(".news_img").stop(true).animate({
            height: "show"
        }, 290);
        $img = $(this).find(".imgswap");
        $img.attr("src", $img.data("hover"));
    }, function () {
        $(this).find(".news_img").stop(true).animate({
            height: "hide"
        }, 290);
        $img = $(this).find(".imgswap");
        $img.attr("src", $img.data("src"));
    });

    $(".imgswap").each(function () {
        $(this).data("src", this.src);
    });
});
```

Here are pics in both IE and FF:

[image: Pic]

Comment: You need to include the relevant code here, not just the screenshots. Not many of us are going to copy the URL and paste it in the address bar just to see your code.

Comment: Your fiddle on my IE11 works fine except for the Plant font shows up like yours.  My IE is version 11.0.9600.16521, Update version: 11.0.4 (KB2925418)

Comment: But judging from your screenshots alone, if I were to hazard a guess it might be an issue between SharePoint and IE.

Comment: **@BoltClock**: **http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/sndGB/** I have attempted several times but it alerted _"Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code."_. As a result, I can only put the link with no format, sorry for this inconvenience.

Comment: **@fnostro**: If I use IE to run the JSFIDDLE link, that works as FF and Chrome but when I use the code with SharePoint, it didn't appear those in IE and it's vice versa with FF and Chrome.

Comment: @Janak: How is SharePoint irrelevant to the question?

Comment: @PMay 1903: See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for help on formatting your code.

Comment: **@BoltClock**: Thank you so much. Can anyone solve my problem, please?

Comment: See this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830440/border-top-left-radius-not-working-in-ie/20323252#20323252