# border-top-left-radius in IE 10 applies to all sides

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I want the border-top-left-radius and border-bottom-left-radius to be 3px and the right side is 0px;

Whenever I add border-top-left-radius it will apply to all sides.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKRkZ.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: border-radius doesn't work on IE10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623380/css-border-radius-doesnt-work-on-ie10)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

use like this

> border-radius: 0px 40px 0px 0px;
>   tested in windows 10 edge and IE 11

Comment: I've already tried this approach. still it's not working.
Here's my code : border-radius : 3px 0px 0px 3px;

Comment: top left =  TopLeft 0px 0px 0px; also i have test this in simulter IE 10 and IE 9 working perfect

Comment: may be some other css over writing this